# How to Return a Generic List (Of T) from a Function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have Following Function within my Class, which I want to return as a Generic List.

```
Public Function ProductTitlePrice(Of T)() As List(Of T) Implements IProductRepository.ProductTitlePrice

    Dim v = (From F In _db.Fstock Where F.GUID = 2
        Select F.STK_NAME, F.SELL_PRICE
        ).ToList


    Return v

End Function
```

Error I get is...

```
Error   2   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of <anonymous type>)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)'.
```

Basically, I want to return a Generic List with Data from my Function, Then I will Call this Function within my Controller and map its data to a ViewModel.

**EDIT**

Based upon the comments below, It seems like its not possible. I have all of my ViewModels within my UI layer, all I want to do is.....Return Data from my DAL Layer, and then handle that data within my UI Layer.

my DAL Function will join data from multiple tables, That is the reason I would like to rely on ViewModels.

For example if my Function in my DAL has the following Code

```
var query = from ug in ent.userGroups
            join u in ent.Users on ug.OwnerUserId = ug.userID
            select new
            {
                Name = u.UserName,
                Id = u.userID
                Group = ug.GroupName
            };
```

How can i return **query** from my Function and then handle the output within my UI layer.

Comment: Well as you do it, you can't - generic (`Of T`) is not anonymous! Generic means, that the argument type will be given at the time of the call and anonymous means, a new set of data created on the fly. The compiler can not return an **unknown type** resp. convert an **unknown type** to a **T**. Your best option is probably some key/value pair, if you want to be really dynamic, or just create and fill a typed model, if you are going to use it often.

Comment: ahaan, then how can I return anonymous List? I want to return only the Data from my Function, and then in a separate project populate my viewModels.

Comment: I don't think generics is the right thing to use here. You should define a model that has STK_NAME and SELL_PRICE properties and return a list of that type.

Comment: Anthony, I already have ViewModel with SellPrice & STK_NAME, above Function is from my DAL layer, I dont want to mix my ViewModels within my DAL layer.

Comment: You can not return anonymous types! If you do not want to use your DAL, then create a typed `Business Layer` (as abstract model) and use it instead.

Comment: Yep... I understand and agree that you don't want to have the DAL reference your UI view models. Do you have a core or domain layer? Create a class there and have the repo return it. Edit: same as what pasty is suggesting

Comment: I have a Data Access Layer & a UI (Front End) which Calls the DAL methods. currently I have ViewModels within my DAL layer, which is wrong. So i am trying to find a way how to separate them.

Comment: SO define DTO's (data transfer objects) in a shared class library. Define a DTO with the two properties (for STK_NAME and SELL_PRICE) and return a list of this DTO type.

Comment: Styxxy, basicly I have ViewModels already within my UI layer, and DTO will look exactly same as my ViewModels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the Following Solution.

- A New Project for DTO's as suggested by Styxxy
- Then use Automapper within my UL to map DTO with my ViewModels.

Here is the Source: http://bengtbe.com/blog/2009/04/14/using-automapper-to-map-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc/